# Terraform Create VM from managed disk issue

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to create a managed disk from the existing snapshot and after that create a VM from that disk.

I am receiving errors while creating the managed disk.

Here is my code.

Main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "copy" {

  name = "myOsDisk1"
  location = "East US"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  create_option = "Copy"
  source_resource_id = var.snapshot_id
  disk_size_gb = "50"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "myterraformvm" {

    name                  = "Test-01"
    location              = "East Us"
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.test.name
    network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.main.id}"]
    vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

    storage_os_disk {
    name              = "${azurerm_managed_disk.copy.name}"
    os_type           = "windows"
    managed_disk_id   = "${azurerm_managed_disk.copy.id}"
    create_option     = "Attach"
    }
}
```

Below is the error

> Error: Error creating/updating Managed Disk "myOsDisk1" (Resource Group "vm-from-snap"): compute.DisksClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidParameter" Message="Entity not of expected type" Target="sourceResourceId"
>
> on main.tf line 44, in resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "copy":
> 44: resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "copy" {

Comment: Your problem is here: `source_resource_id = var.snapshot_id`. What are you using for the `snaphot_id`?

Comment: You need to give more messages about the snapshot, such as the way that how do you create it? And give more Terraform code.

Comment: @John Hanley  In var.snapshot_id contains the resource id of the snapshot.  It was created from the portal manually. I need to use that resource id to create that managed disk.

Comment: @Charles Xu . The snapshot was created using azure portal. Do i need to import the resource & then create the managed disk using the snapshot resource id ?

Comment: Does the managed disk you want to create in the same subscription and region with the snapshot?

Comment: Without details on the correct/wrong snapshot ID, this question lacks details. I vote to close this question.

Comment: @Charles Xu - Yes its in same subscription & same region.

Comment: Then it's wired, all things work fine on my side.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, you could verify if you have input the correct `source_resource_id`. The variable snapshot can be decalred like this format:

```
variable "snapshot_id" {
  default = "/subscriptions/<xxxsubIdxxx>/resourceGroups/<rgName>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/snapshots/<snapshotName>"

}
```

Step 1: create the snapshot with the Azure portal,

[image]

Step 2: Copy the snapshot Id to the variable `snapshot_id` above.

[image]
At last, I suggest upgrading the terraform to the latest version or 0.12 above. All things work well on my side.

```
Terraform v0.14.4
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.43.0
```

Comment: Thanks All. The issue is fixed, I declared the snapshot information in datasource.tf